# dynamic method loading according to micro benchmark in page

Tags: javascript, web, benchmarking, microbenchmark

I had an idea, and want to know if there is anything out there like this...

The page loads, and javascript needs to iterate over a long list of data. There are many ways to iterate the list in javascript, and some methods work faster on different browsers. Usually, a good method is chosen as a compromise between all the popular browsers - so maybe not choosing the fastest method, but one that is not terribly slow on any browser.

Is it possible to instead, load several methods, and test them, on a small list, perhaps with only 20 cycles each, and then dynamically choose that method for the rest of the page?

Could there be any performance improvement from this approach?

Is there anything like that out there?

Comment: Great question. I have recently had the same thought. Of course, this is reserved only for the most heavily used methods where performance differs significantly across browsers, and not only reserved to list comprehension/iteration, but also to other algorithms that can be optimized in different ways.